# WAMP MySQL PDO_extension error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp, wampserver

I want to connect MySQL database using PDO Extension. I am using PHP 5.4

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8080;dbname=films_db;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee";

$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}

$result->closeCursor();
```

But, my WAMP server is not responding. I am not getting any result. Its "Waiting for localhost" state and getting server timeout error.

Pls help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: have you enabled `PDO` extension in WAMP server?

Comment: As always when you get an unexpected result from a web server: LOOK INTO THE SERVERS LOG FILES! Especially the error log file, since that is where syntax and runtime errors are logged to. On Linux that is something like /var/log/apache2/error_log, not sure about Windoze.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar : I am using PHP 5.4 (Yep it is enabled)

Comment: @vlcekmi3 : No, still "Waiting for localhost". but not getting any result. When I comment "'mysql:host=localhost;port=8080;dbname=films_db;charset=UTF-8'". The server is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 8080 is for http,
normally it does not used for mysql.

and the default mysql port is 3306.
You might need to check your mysql setting to "confirm" the actual port being used.

Beside this, you might need to check how many record in the table employee.
If millions of records, it might be the reason it takes time to load.

Comment: So, what I have to do pls.... No I have only two or three records. MySQL port is 3306. But I have to user localhost port no?

Comment: If your mysql port is 3306, then your PDO dsn should change to 3306 accordingly instead of 8080